# Insert to database using a batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I want to make some SQL operations with a batch file but it doesn't work.
Here are the contents of the batch file. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong..

```
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysql.exe -h localhost --user=root  --password=mariette -e connect quizz -e INSERT INTO `quizz`.`jeu1` (
`index` ,
`user` ,
`password` ,
`score`
)
VALUES (
NULL , 'chris', 'qsdfg', '25'
);

pause
```

Comment: If `index` is your primary key, it can not be `NULL`.

Comment: try enclosing your sql statement in double quotes

Comment: it does work in phpmyadmin ! (it's code I've pasted from the automatic code from phpmyadmin)...but not in my batch file...

Answer (score 2):

Cannot use new lines like that in batch file.Try this

```
set "query=INSERT INTO `quizz`.`jeu1` (`index` ,`user` ,`password` ,`score`) VALUES ( NULL , 'chris', 'qsdfg', '25');"
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysql.exe -h localhost --user=root  --password=mariette -e connect quizz -e "%query%"
pause
```

Or like this:

```
set query=INSERT INTO `quizz`.`jeu1` (`index` ,`user` ,`password` ,`score`)^
 VALUES ^
 ( NULL , 'chris', 'qsdfg', '25');

c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysql.exe -h localhost --user=root  --password=mariette -e connect quizz -e  "%query%"
pause
```

Here new line is escaped with `^` for more readable code.Not sure if query is correct.

Comment: I believe `%query%` should be quoted so that it is interpreted as a single argument. Also, your 2nd code must escape the quotes in the SET statement, otherwise `^` is treated as a literal. I don't see the need for the intermediate QUERY variable. The SQL query string can be supplied directly on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You should better to join your SQL syntax in a single SQL file and act like:

```
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysql.exe -hlocalhost -uroot -pmariette DATABASE < /path/to/dump.sql
```

here `/path/to/dump.sql` indicates absolute path to file `dump.sql` which should contain your SQL commands. `DATABASE` should be replaced with actual name of the database, on which you are operating.

This is better because if you'll want to change SQL, you will need to change only SQL-file, not the command itself.